# compute a shape from a list of geographical coordinates

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geometry, shapes, area

I have an App that displays thousands of Pin annotations on a google map using geo coordinates (lat/long in degree).
In some circumstances I would like to replace the Pin annotations with an overlay that will represent the shape of my geographical area covered by my thousands of Pin.

I'm looking for an algorithm where the input is the list of geo coordinate of my Pin annotations and the output will be an ordered list of geo coordinates that I will use to create the overlay on the google map. For sure the best would be java/objective-C code if it exists :-)

I looked on internet and found articles related to Graham convex hull algorithm but it seems not so easy to use and I don't know if it really works with Lat/Long?

Any help will be really appreciated.
Regards,

Sébastien.

Comment: Javascript certainly exists. http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp

Comment: If your lat/long are not spread over too wide an area (less than a quarter of the globe or so) then you won't go too far wrong pretending that lat/long are plane coordinates, but take care of wrapping around at long +/-180deg.  And, given the display size and resolution available to most apps, any imprecision arising from pretending that lat/long are plane coordinates will be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this is what you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Comment: Yes, it should help me for what I have to do. Thanks!